# How can I write a set of equations in summation form?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, notation, systems-of-equations

I have a system of equations as follows:

\begin{align}
& A_1^{11} + A_1^{12} + A_1^{13} + \cdots + A_1^{1n}=X \\[8pt]
& A_1^{21} + A_1^{22} + A_1^{23} + \cdots+ A_1^{2n}=X \\[8pt]
& \qquad \vdots \\[8pt]
& A_1^{n1} + A_1^{n2} + A_1^{n3} + \cdots + A_1^{nn}=X \\[8pt]
& A_2^{11} + A_2^{12} + A_2^{13} + \cdots + A_2^{1n}=X \\[8pt]
& \qquad\vdots \\[8pt]
& A_2^{n1} + A_2^{n2} + A_2^{n3} + \cdots + A_2^{nn}=X \\[8pt]
& \qquad\vdots \\[8pt]
& A_m^{11} + A_m^{12} + A_m^{13} + \cdots + A_m^{1n}=X \\[8pt]
& \qquad\vdots \\[8pt]
& A_m^{n1} + A_m^{n2} + A_m^{n3} + \cdots + A_m^{nn}=X
\end{align}

How can I write these equations in a summation form?

Comment: is it supposed to be the same $X$ for all indices?

Comment: Yes, same $X$ for all indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write $$\sum_{i=1}^nA_j^{ki}=X$$ with the point being that this equation is true for all $j,k$.  You have $mn$ equations here, each one summing over one of the indices on $A$.

Comment: If I´m right then there are $m\cdot n$ equations.

Comment: So, is it like this $$\sum_{i=1}^nA_j^{ki}=X$$ $  $$\forall j\in \{1,2,3,..,m\} $$ ; \forall k\in \{1,2,3,..,n\} $

Comment: @usr109876787 That´s right. And this leads to $m\cdot n$ equations.

Comment: @callculus:  I missed that $j$ went up to $m$, not $n$.  Fixed.  Thanks